# Which sets of positive rationals are closed under addition?

Tags: power-series, rational-numbers

This question evolved because I was interested in generalizing power series
so the exponents were rational numbers instead of integers,
i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n x^{r_n}$,
with the $a_i$ real and the $r_i$  non-negative rationals.

The theorem I wanted to hold was that if the product of two
such series was zero, then one of the series had to be zero.

I quickly realized that
for the series to be meaningful,
the $r_i$  could not have any
accumulation point.

This means that there had to be a positive real $c$
such that
$r_{i+1} \ge r_i+c$ for all $i$.

Also, for the ordinary Cauchy product of these series
to have the same exponents,
the series had to be closed under addition,
so that, for each pair of exponents
$r_i$ and $r_j$,
there is an exponent $r_k$ such that
$r_i+r_j = r_k$.

An obvious set of such rationals
is $(\frac{i}{n})_{i=0}^{\infty}$
for $n$ a positive integer.

My question is this:

Are there any other sets of non-negative rationals
without any accumulation point
which
are closed under addition?

Comment: not quite answering your question, but did you read about generalized power series already?

Comment: I should point out that the statement "The $r_i$ could not have any accumulation point" doesn't actually imply "there had to be a positive real $c$ s.t. $r_i+1\geq r_i+c$ for all $i$"; consider the harmonic series $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i$.  Then $H_n$ has no accumulation point, but there's no lower bound on the gap between successive terms.  Unless you're implying that the closure under addition implies a lower bound for the gap, in which case I'd like to see the argument for that (I tried to prove that myself and couldn't).

Comment: But the terms making up $H_n$ $do$ have an accumulation point (0).

Comment: @martycohen Agreed, but if you imagine ignoring where the $H_n$ come from and just setting your $r_n=H_n$, then there would be no accumulation point and also no minimal bound between terms.  It's not clear to me that an 'additively closed' sequence couldn't also exhibit such behavior - in fact, thinking about it more I can give an explicit example of one that does...

Comment: @martycohen Consider the sequence $r_n=\{\frac12, 1, 1\frac14, 1\frac24, 1\frac34, 2, 2\frac18, 2\frac28, 2\frac38, \ldots, 3, 3\frac1{16}, 3\frac2{16}, \ldots\}$ .  This set is clearly additively closed, it has no accumulation point, but there's no lower bound on the difference between successive $r_n$.

Comment: @martycohen What's more, for this sequence there are $2^{n+1}$ terms with exponent between $n$ and $n+1$, so for instance if the $a_n$ are bounded then as long as $x\lt \frac12$ there's no barrier to convergence despite the shrinking gap between successive terms.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be very satisfying considering what you're looking for, but you could remove part of the beginning part of the set and retain this property.   These are called [numerical semigroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup), if $0$ is included. For example, $$\{0,3,5,6,8,9,10,\ldots\}=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,2,4,7\}$$
(and of course you can divide this by any denominator you like).

A perhaps more appealing solution is to take an additive subsemigroup of $\mathbb{N}$ that is *not* a numerical semigroup, i.e. that has a common divisor, and put it over a relatively prime denominator.  For example,
$$\left\{\frac{2n}{7}:n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Fleshing out my comments into an answer: the 'meaningfulness' (which I take to mean 'having a positive convergence radius') and additive-closed nature of the series are not enough in and of themselves to guarantee a lower bound on $r_{n+1}-r_n$; there is an example (in fact, many examples) of a sequence of exponents $r_n$ such that series of the form $a_nx^{r_n}$ with $a_n\in\Theta(1)$ have a positive radius of convergence and with $r_n$ additively closed but $\lim_{n\to\infty}(r_{n+1}-r_n)=0$.

For the simplest (to me) example, consider $r_n$ defined such that $r_{2^i+j}=i+\frac{j}{2^i}$ if $j\lt2^i$; i.e., $r_1=0$, $r_2=1$, $r_3=1\!\frac12$, $r_4=2$, $r_5=2\!\frac14$, etc.  Then it's easy to see that $r_n$ is additively closed; $r_a+r_b\ (b\gt a)$ can't have a 'dyadic denominator' larger than that of $r_b$, and all such numbers $\geq r_b$ are in the sequence.  What's more, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{r_n}$, the prototypical example of a 'rational power series' (the analogue to the geometric series), converges for $0\leq x\lt\frac12$; for we can break it into a double sum $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{2^i-1}x^{(i+j2^{-i})}$.  Each term in the inner sum is $\leq x^i$ if $x\lt1$, so the entire inner sum is bounded by $2^ix^i$ and the sum as a whole is bounded by $\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^ix^i$, which clearly converges for $x\lt\frac12$.

Picking other denominators for the sequence of $r$s will give plenty of other examples of additively-closed sequences under the looser conditions I'm using here, and you can combine this with Vadim's suggestion of removing initial subsets to provide many more examples.  On the other hand, all of these techniques only provide countably many examples of sequences $r_n$, and I suspect that the set of all such sequences (additively closed and 'exponentially bounded', which I believe is the right accumulation condition to imply - it's the statement that there's some $C$ s.t. for all $n$ there are only $C^n$ members of the sequence $r_i$ less than $n$) is in fact actually countable, but I can't see any easy proof for that.